# Android: Constraints to a base view vs reuse of margin value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I can't find any documentation about performance or best practice, but what I'm trying to find out is if there is a better choice to design layouts when needing similar spacing. I'm sure there will be some situational preferences based on the entirety of the layout, but in terms of the specific situation provided is there a clear better option?

1. Use more constraints to a "base" view for other views to align against
2. Use the same margin `dimen` value for the other views.

### 1. Constraints to base that has margins set

[image: Constraints to base that has margins set]

### 2. Using the same margin value for all views

[image: Using the same margin value for all views]

Comment: This is such a micro-optimisation, that it really doesn't matter. There is no clear better option.